# self constraint protocol extention for UIViewController

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-protocols

I'm working on a legacy Swift 2.2 project, and I want to implement some well-known protocol-oriented practices to my code.

```
protocol SuccessPresenting {
    func presentSucess(title: String, message: String)
}

extension SuccessPresenting where Self: UIViewController {
    func presentSucess(title: String?, message: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ОК", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(dismissAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class NewViewController: UIViewController, SuccessPresenting {

   func foo() {
      presentSucess(nil, message: "Done!")
   }
}
```

Though, it is works on Swift 3.1, here I get an error: `The NewViewController doesn't conform to protocol SuccessPresenting`

But why should I write protocol implementation in my VC, as I have already done that using protocol extension?
I'll appreciate any help.
Please remind, this is Swift 2.2

Comment: try deleting the `SuccessPresenting` conformance constraint from your `NewViewController`. i.e. `class NewViewController: UIViewController { // code that calls presentSuccess }`

Comment: @NandiinBao That didn't help me either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a direct paste? Because your `extension` contains an optional instead of a regular string, whereas your protocol has a normal `String`. This might cause the compiler to regard it is a different method, rendering the `optionallness` of your protocol invalid in this particular case.

Comment: Oh, thanks God stackOverFlow exist. Of course, you are right, I was inattentive )